# Avoid 406 error when using GET method in API testing with Cypress

Tags: json, testing, cypress, web-api-testing, http-status-code-406

I would like to test the api of an application, I've got a token from the developer, but I'm getting an error 'cy.request() failed on:

https://******************************

The response we received from your web server was:

> 406: Not Acceptable

This was considered a failure because the status code was not 2xx or 3xx.'
This is the code that I used:

```
describe('API Test', () => {
    const token = 'your_token_here';

    it('Should make a GET request with a Bearer token and avoid 406 error', () => {
        cy.request({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://your-api.com/endpoint',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then((response) => {
            expect(response.status).to.eq(200);
            expect(response.body).to.be.an('object');
        });
    });
});
```

I tried with 'Accept': 'application/json' and 'Content-Type': 'application/json', but it didn't help.

Comment: is your request works fine with postman ?

Comment: @AhmedSbai I haven't try but when I open the url in the browser, it shows me data in json format. The data is correct

Comment: look at my answer maybe it helps